# Recurrence relation for binary strings of length $n$ that doesnt contain $010$ pattern?

Tags: recurrence-relations

I've looked up this question in here and found one whose answer didnt look complete to me or maybe I couldnt figure it out correctly.. 
I can understand the first part of the answer
$a_n = a_{n-1} + a_{n-3} + a_{n-4} + a_{n-5} + \cdots + a_{1} + 3$
But my problem mosly is on last part
$a_1 + 3$
Any help like "explanation for dummies" kind of answer would be great ! 
What is the best approach to analyze these kinda problems ..
The related link:
[$n$-Bit Strings Not Containing $010$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454509/n-bit-strings-not-containing-010)
Thanks a lot !

Comment: Can you link to the other question?  This formula doesn't look right.  Aside from the two $a_{n-3}$ terms (which I figure is a typo) the formula says $a_2=a_1+3$.  But there are two good strings of length $1$ and $4$ of length $2$ so this is not the right answer.

Comment: @lulu im sorry for being careless, for the answer ,I edited the question with the link added ..

Comment: The explanation to that question seems thorough.  The "$+3$" arises because prepending strings of the form $0^k11$ does not get you any of the three strings $0^n,0^{n-1}1,0^{n-2}11$.   Note that the explanation specifically says this recursion only holds for $n≥3$, excluding the counterexample I pointed out earlier.  Note, this is not how I would have thought about the problem...are you trying to understand how to construct these strings recursively or are you trying to understand this particular recursion?

Comment: On a tangential note, I think $a_{n}=2a_{n-1}-a_{n-2}+a_{n-3}$ also works. First term counts how to add $0$ or $1$, second term takes out strings that end with $10$, third term adds back strings ending with $110$, so only those ending with $010$ are removed.

Comment: @lulu thanks for the tips , I have only a half understanding of forming recurrences like these, specially as soon as I think I know already how to find a correct recursive solution for these kind of problem , I suddenly encounter new one with s strange form(to me). And I conclude that I have omitted some aspects of the recurrence! Its still vague and unclear to me, trying to find it out . Thank u so much

Comment: @kevin long Thanks for the reply kevin, im trying to figure out your approach, it makes more sense to me.. im grateful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think understanding the $+ 3$ revolves around understanding the first bits so bare with me as I explain my interpretation. First, keep in mind that if we have a "good" string (one that meets the given requirements) of length $n-1$ and append a $1$ to the start, we will always get a "good" string of length $n$, since adding a $1$ to the front can't create an occurrence of $010$. This contributes the $S_{n-1}$ term.

However, the string needn't necessarily begin with $1$. It could start with some string of $0$'s. Now, we assume two things: the first is that the string of $0$'s is followed by $11$ and secondly, that the $11$ is followed by a good string. This is because we know that if $1$ follows a $0$ in the string, then to make it a good string, that $1$ must be followed by another $1$. Then, we'll have something of the form $000...011$+[good string]. Then since $010$ occurs in neither of the concatenated strings, nor in the part where they meet, then the result is a good string. Thus, we begin with $011$+[good string of length $n-3$] contributing $S_{n-3}$, $0011$+[good string of length $n-3$] contributing $S_{n-4}$, and so on until we get to a string of $n-3$ $0$'s, $11$ and then $0$ or $1$, which is counted by $S_{1}=2$.

Now we consider the exceptions: as I said before, we assume, among other things, that there is something following the $11$ buffer. However, we could have $00...011$, which is a good string. We also might not even have the $11$ buffer: we can also have $00...01$ and $00...0$. In these cases, the complete buffer is not necessary. However, in any other case where we have a string of $0$'s followed by $1$ followed by at least $2$ entries, then we refer to the previous cases.