# How many binary strings (with a given number of occurrences of 0 and 1) are there that do not contain a given substring?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations, combinations, bit-strings

I know my binary string is composed of exactly $n$ $1$s and $m$ $0$s. How many such strings are possible, if we add the constraint that they must not contain a specific given substring $S$ (whose length is $\leq n+m$)?

I am specifically interested in the answer in the case that $S=010$.

Note: I know how to determine the answer programatically / via dynamic programming. I'm looking for a more closed form / combinatoric solution.

For example, if $n=3$, $m=2$, and $S=010$, then the following would be all $7$ relevant ways:
$$00111$$
$$01101$$
$$01110$$
$$10011$$
$$10110$$
$$11001$$
$$11100$$

Comment: Note:  on first reading, I missed the condition that the number of $1's$ and $0's$ is specified.  [This question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/454509/n-bit-strings-not-containing-010) just deals with strings of a fixed length.  Relevant, but not a duplicate.

Comment: The Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method : https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9806036v1.pdf

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This answer is based upon the *[Goulden-Jackson Cluster Method](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/9806036)*.

> We consider the set words of length $n\geq 0$ built from an alphabet $$\mathcal{V}=\{0,1\}$$ and the set $B=\{010\}$ of *bad words*, which are not allowed to be part of the words we are looking for. We derive a generating function $f(s)$ with the coefficient of $s^n$ being  the number of searched words of length $n$.

According to the paper (p.7) the generating function $f(s)$  is
\begin{align*}
f(s)=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\tag{1}
\end{align*}
with $d=|\mathcal{V}|=2$, the size of the alphabet and $\mathcal{C}$ the *weight-numerator* of bad words with
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[010])
\end{align*}

> We calculate according to the paper
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[010])&=-s^3-s^2\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[010])\tag{1}\\
> \end{align*}
>
> and get
>   \begin{align*}
> \text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=-\frac{s^3}{1+s^2}
> \end{align*}
>
> It    follows
>
> \begin{align*}
> f(s)&=\frac{1}{1-ds-\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})}\\
> &=\frac{1}{1-2s+\frac{s^3}{1+s^2}}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{1+s^2}{1-2s+s^2-s^3}\\
> &=1+2s+4s^2+7s^3+12s^4+\color{blue}{21}s^5\\
> &\qquad+37s^6+65s^7+114s^8+200s^9+351s^{10}+\cdots
> \end{align*}
>
> The last line was calculated with the help of Wolfram Alpha.  The coefficient   of $s^5$  shows there are $\color{blue}{21}$ valid words of  length $5$ from the alphabet $\{0,1\}$ which do not contain the word $010$.

But we want to also keep track of the number of $0$'s and $1$'s. We get a refinement of $f(s)$ by marking the $0$ with $x$ and the $1$'s with $y$. We obtain from (1)
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[010])&=-x^2ys^3-xys^2\text{weight}(\mathcal{C}[010])
\end{align*}
and get
\begin{align*}
\text{weight}(\mathcal{C})=-\frac{x^2ys^3}{1+xys^2}
\end{align*}

> Using this generalized weight we obtain from (2) a generating  function $g(s;x,y)$
>   \begin{align*}
> g(s;x,y)&=\frac{1}{1-(x+y)s+\frac{x^2ys^3}{1+xys^2}}\\
> &=\frac{1+xys^2}{1-(x+y)s+xys^2-xy^2s^3}\\
> &=1+(x+y)s+(x^2+2xy+y^2)s^2+(x^3+2x^2y+3xy^2+y^3)\\
> &\qquad+(x^4+2x^3y+4x^2y^2+4xy^3+y^4)s^4\\
> &\qquad+(x^5+2x^4y+5x^3y^2+\color{red}{7}x^2y^3+5xy^4+y^5)s^5+\cdots
> \end{align*}

So, e.g. out of $2^5=32$ binary  words of length $5$ there are $\color{blue}{21}$ valid words which do not contain $010$ and $\color{red}{7}$ of them contain $n=2$ zeros and $m=3$ ones:

\begin{array}{cccc}
\qquad\color{blue}{00000}\qquad&\qquad01000\qquad&\qquad\color{blue}{10000}\qquad&\qquad\color{blue}{11000}\qquad\\
\color{blue}{00001}&01001&\color{blue}{10001}&\color{red}{11001}\\
00010&01010&10010&11010\\
\color{blue}{00011}&01011&\color{red}{10011}&\color{blue}{11011}\\
00100&\color{blue}{01100}&10100&\color{red}{11100}\\
00101&\color{red}{01101}&10101&\color{blue}{11101}\\
\color{blue}{00110}&\color{red}{01110}&\color{red}{10110}&\color{blue}{11110}\\
\color{red}{00111}&\color{blue}{01111}&\color{blue}{10111}&\color{blue}{11111}\\
\end{array}

Comment: How do you use WolframAlpha to compute the polynomial division for your final $g(s;x,y)$? I also have Wolfram Mathematica, but I cannot even get that to do the expansion..

Comment: You could type: "series <expression in s,x,y> at s=0". This tells WA to expand at $s=0$ and arrange powers accordingly. For the expression above I used: "series 1/(1-(x+y)*s+x^2*y*s^3/(1+x*y*s^2)) at s=0 ".

Comment: @MarkusScheuer For example if the question were asking $1100113$ as bad word , then the generalized $g(s,x,y,z)= -x^4y^2z s^7 - xyzs^n weight(C[1100113])$ where x=1 ,y=0 ,z=3 , am I right ? Is it the logic of generalization

Comment: @Bulbasaur: In this case it is simply $-x^4y^2zs^7$ without any additional terms, since we do not have any overlaps. We also have to set $d=3$ since the alphabet consists now of three characters.

Comment: @MarkusScheuer  thank you Mr. Scheuer , i got the logic. You made very  big contribution to my education with your techniques  and comments. By the way , if there were any overlap , would it be $xyzs^{something}weight (C[v])$ , right ?

Comment: @Bulbasaur: You're welcome! :-) and yes, the presentation is correct. Note, there might be more than one overlap depending on the structure of the bad word.

Answer (score 0):

A recurrence and generating function.

For the case $S=010$, let $T_{n,m}$ be the number of ways.

$$T_{n,0}=1, T_{n,1}=n+1, T_{0,m}=1, T_{1,m}=2$$

The total with $n,m>1$, can be computed by recursion.

There are $T_{n-1,m}$ cases that end with $1$.

There are $T_{n,m-2}$ cases that end with $00$.

There are $T_{n-2,m-1}$ cases that end with $110$.

So $$T_{m,n} = T_{n-1,m}+T_{n,m-2} + T_{n-2,m-1}$$

From there, it is going to take some work to get a closed formula. You can probably use generating functions to get one. Letting:

$$f(x,y)=\sum_{m,n} T_{n,m}x^ny^m$$

The recurrence should give us something simple for:

$$f(x,y)(1-x-y^2-x^2y)=\sum_{m,n} a_{n,m}x^ny^m$$

The recurrense means that if $m,n>1$, then $a_{n,m}=0$.

My brain is having trouble getting the rest of this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a total of $\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}$ strings of binary sequences with $m$ ones and $n$ zeros. There are $m+n-k*(S_m-S_n)+1$ spots where you could have $k$ strings $S$, where $S_n$ is the number of zeros in the string and $S_m$ is the number of ones in the string. The full formula is then
$$\frac{(m+n)!}{m!n!}-\sum_{k=1}^G \frac{(m-kS_m+n-kS_n+k)!}{(m-kS_m)!(n-kS_n)!k!}$$ where $G=\left\lfloor\frac{m+n}{S_m+S_n}\right\rfloor$.

Comment: Your formula fails on the example case I provided in my question. Specifically, plugging in my provided example for your answer, we have $m=3$, $n=2$, and $S=010$. Thus, $S_n=2$, $S_m=1$, $G=1$, and your formula yields $9\neq 7$.

Comment: Sorry about that. I forgot to add a one in the numerator.

Comment: @user1145925 My new formula produces the correct answer.

Comment: Your new formula produces the correct answer for the specific case in the question. But modifying to $m=2$ and $n=3$, it gives the wrong answer. Enumerating, these are the $5$ possible strings: [00011, 00110, 01100, 10001, 11000], whereas your formula gives $4$.

Comment: I should be doing something along the lines of stars and bars, with $S$ representing a bar and everything else representing a star. I'll work on this.

Comment: I think the problem with my formula and that example is that it counts $[01010]$ twice as $[(010)10]$ and $[01(010)]$.